# How to read query string in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs4, query-string

I have an ExtJS application which is invoked with some query string parameters. I would like to know how to read those parameters and their values using ExtJS 4.

My ExtJS application URL will look like the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp?candidate_id=101&candidate_id=102&candidate_id=103
```

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, that question is related to jquery...not about extjs 4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `Ext.Object.fromQueryString` like this

```
Ext.Object.fromQueryString('candidate_id=101&candidate_id=102&candidate_id=103')
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-fromQueryString

Comment: but 'candidate_id=101&candidate_id=102&candidate_id=103' this part is not static. it will keep changing i.e. number of times candidate_id mentioned in querystring  can change from 3 to 10 or 1

Comment: you can get your query string by `document.location.href.split('?')[1]`, so you can use this value to for **fromQueryString** method. this method will give you an object. if `candidate_id` mentioned more than once it will give you an array for `candidate_id`

Comment: Use `location.search` to pass the parameters to `Ext.Object.fromQueryString`

Comment: Using document.location.search has a big advantage over using document.location.href.split(?). If no search part is given in the url like in http://www.google.de the split will return an undefined. This will lead to an exception in the Ext.Object.fromQueryString method. Using document.location.search will return an empty string and will not crash when no search path is provided! Thx Jaider